# Translate System.out.format to Clojure

Tags: java, class, clojure, format, interop

I have written some utility programs in Java, and now I just want to
translate it into *Clojure*. I am running into some snags with
classes. Clojure touts that it has seamless interoperation with Java,
but I have not been able to find good solution from Google. Please
help. Thanks.

I want to use Java classes directly (I don't want to use clojure
"format" function yet because I just want to see how the
*clojure-java-interop* works out):

```
System.out.format("Enter number of points: ");
```

What I have done is:

```
(def x (. System out))
```

but then everything I tried to do to use format failed:

```
(. x format "foo")
(. x (format "foo"))
(.format x)
(.format "foo")
(. x format)
(. x #(format))
(. x #(format %) "s")
(.format x "foo")
((.format x) "foo")
(x/format "foo")
(x. format "%s" "foo")
(. x format "%s" "s")
(. x format "%s" ["s"])
(def y (System.out.))
(def y (System.out.format.))
(format x "s")
```

And what about translating System.exit(0) to clojure?

```
(. System exit 0)
```

does seem to work. But why doesn't similar translation work for "System.out.format"?

I seem like a monkey typing on the key board hoping to produce Hamlet!

Please help ! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out.format` takes in variable arguments. The way java dispatches var args functions is by shoving the rest of the arguments into an Object array. This could be achieved in clojure like so:

```
(. System/out format "abc" (into-array []))
(. System/out format "abc %d" (into-array [12]))

;; or use the more intuitive
(.format System/out "abc %d" (into-array[12]))
```

actually lots of your attempts were really very close:

```
(def x (. System out))
(. x format "foo" (into-array[]))
(. x (format "foo" (into-array[])))
(.format x "foo" (into-array[]))
(. x format "%s" (into-array["foo"]))
```

However, pay attention, this will print out to the repl console and not necessarily to what your ide shows.

To show it like clojure would, instead of using the java's `System.out` object, use clojure's `*out*`:

```
(. *out* format "abc %d" (into-array [12])) 
;; "abc 12"
```

**EDIT**

It seems that your `*out*` is defined as a [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) which does not have the method `format`. Not sure why, but you could overcome this using binding, for example:

```
user=> (binding [*out* System/out]
         (. *out* format "abc %d" (into-array[12])))
abc 12#object[java.io.PrintStream 0x4efb0c88 "java.io.PrintStream@4efb0c88"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was specifically trying to test Cjoures's claim that it can work with Java "seamlessly". In general, how do you translate Java code: object1.object2.object3.object4.object5.objectnth.method(arg1, arg2, argn) to Clojure?

Comment: I have an answer for you, its long with examples :) however I think you should ask a new question for it and if this answers your current question then kindly accept it.

Comment: Okay, that is great ! and thank you so much for your help ! I will post another question and will title it : "Converting java object and method calls to Clojure codes."

Comment: I went home and tested \*out\*; it did not work as expected: user=> (. \*out\* (format "%d" (into-array [3])))
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: format for class java.io.OutputStreamWriter  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
user=> (format "%d" 3)
"3"
I have to do it without the \*out\*;

Comment: @lisprogtor that's because you accidentally wrapped the format part with parenthesis. If you leave them out it would mean "execute format method on object /*out/* with these params"

Comment: Thanks Shlomi. I tested it without the parentheses as well: XubuntuVBox1404i32clojure-1.8.0> java -cp clojure-1.8.0.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.8.0
user=> (. \*out\* format "abc %d" (into-array [12]))
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: format for class java.io.OutputStreamWriter  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
user=> \*out\*
#object[java.io.OutputStreamWriter 0x1ca8d36 "java.io.OutputStreamWriter@1ca8d36"]
user=> 
Is this weird or is it just my system?

Comment: Strange, it works on my system with both clojure 1.8 and 1.9.. Could you ask a question about it listing your project.clj as well?

Comment: Thank you Shlomi. I don't have a project.clj. I just opened the REPL from command prompt. \*out\* is defined, but the format method did not work on my particular system, which is a linux mint in virtualbox. I guess I will try to use Clojure 1.9 to see if the problem goes away. Thanks again !!!

Comment: It seems your /*out/* is of type [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) which has no method named `format`. You could define /*out/* to be `PrintWriter` (as in my setup) using [bindings](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/-28O6UWB35o) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure already has a [`printf`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/printf) function that does the same thing as [`PrintStream.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), except that it prints specifically to [`*out*`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*out*):

```clj
(printf "Enter number of points: ")
;; Enter number of points: 

(printf "abc %d" 12)
;; abc 12
```